# Почему событие не выполняется над переменной int i;

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    int i = 0; //эта переменная не выполняется в обработчике дважды
               // происходит переинициализация 

    LinkButton link = new LinkButton();

    public void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++; //здесь происходит событие увеличения переменной i
        link.Text = i;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        link.Text = "+++";
        link.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);

        form.Controls.Add(l); 
        form.Controls.Add(link)
    }
}
```

Точнее оно выполняется однажды так, как будто вся страница инициализируется заново, но в саму инициализацию линка добавляются старые данные.

суть в том что статические данные изменяются, но остаются в памяти при сбросе даже браузера.
если не изменят код проекта то следующий запуск приложения выдаёт те данные которые были инициализированы в предыдущем

```
class ins
{
    public static int i; 
    public void count() { i++; }
    public static int getI() { return i; }

}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Во-первых, это WinForms? Во-вторых, опишите точно, что вы видите. В-третьих, почему бы вам не поставить breakpoint'ы в интересующих вас функциях и узнать, вызываются ли функции, и сколько раз?

Comment: @VKonstantin, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @VladD, судя по наследованию: WebForms